# discord.py ways eval(string)

Tags: python, discord.py

This is my code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Compile(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(name = 'say')
    async def SayCommand(self, ctx, query):
        cmd = await ctx.send(eval(query))
    
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Compile(bot))
```

I'm trying to get my bot to respond depending on the python I enter with the `t.say` command. E.g. `t.say print('hello')` would result in the bot returning `Hello`.

However, I'm running into this error:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing (<string>, line 1)
```

Comment: This technically isn't an answer but since I can't comment: EOF happens when you have mismatching parentheses or loops with no body, or these sort of errors Try printing `query` before doing eval and see what does it actually print, and if it is indeed `print('hello')` and nothing else, trying doing this: `cmd = await ctx.send(eval(f"{query}"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eval()` is strictly to be used for expressions, not statements. To make your code work, use `exec()`

E.g.

```
@commands.command(name = 'say')
    async def SayCommand(self, ctx, query):
        cmd = await ctx.send(exec(query))
```

I'm assuming that you're doing this to allow for other python code to be ran. If not, I suggest you just use a command which `ctx.send(query)` back, and skip using python code in the command call.